# Объединение ключей массива по группам

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив полей формы, где каждое поле представлено в виде уникального подмассива:

```html
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => field1
        [value] => гендир
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => field2
        [value] => Виктор
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => field1
        [value] => секретарь
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => field2
        [value] => Юлия
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => field1
        [value] => дворник
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => field2
        [value] => Вася
    )
)
```

Необходимо получить следующий массив:

```html
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   [name] => field1
   [value] => гендир
  )

 [1] => Array
  (
   [name] => field2
   [value] => Виктор
  )
)
[1] => Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   [name] => field1
   [value] => секретарь
  )

 [1] => Array
  (
   [name] => field2
   [value] => Юлия
  )
)
[2] => Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   [name] => field1
   [value] => дворник
  )

 [1] => Array
  (
   [name] => field2
   [value] => Вася
  )
)
)
```

Т.е. необходимо при повторении ключа и значения выделить все нижеследующие элементы (включая повторяющийся ключ:значение) в отдельный подмассив. Каким образом можно выполнить подобное преобразование средствами PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения желаемого результата вам следует реализовать цикл,  в котором проверять имя поля. И когда оно равно `field1` следует переключать индекс результирующего массива.

```
$result = [];
$idx = 0;

foreach($data as $d){
    if($d['name'] == "field1"){
        $idx++;
        $v = [];
    }
    $result[$idx][] = $d;
}
```

С другой стороны, возможно вам будет удобнее несколько иной результат группировки:

```
[1] => Array (
        [field1] => гендир
        [field2] => Виктор
    )

[2] => Array (
        [field1] => секретарь
        [field2] => Юлия
    )

[3] => Array (
        [field1] => дворник
        [field2] => Вася
    )
```

что получается при замене основной рабочей строки цикла на

```
$result[$idx][$d['name']] = $d['value'];
```